# Is it possible to edit a Lua file real-time on ios

Tags: c++, ios, lua

I am currently incorporating a scripting language into my engine, and after much research it seems LUA is the most appropriate in terms of platform compatibility and speed. After investigating, little has turned up as to whether a user will be able to edit LUA files within my iOS application in real-time.

The objective would be to have a single-line console input, to modify the environment, and then save back to file, ready to repeat the script on next load. I am cautious to advance, as I am unsure if the sandbox limitations over the I/O file systems would not allow this type of behavior.

Comment: As for your question "Is it possible to edit a LUA file real-time on ios", the answer is "yes".

Comment: @phresnel I don't think so. There's no programming language called "LUA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `luaL_loadstring` to load arbitrary C strings, so yes. Just write the code that accesses the iOS filesystem yourself and use `luaL_loadstring` to load them.

See the [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/) for details.

(By the way, it's Lua, not LUA. It isn't an acronym)